# AWS batch cloudformation - “CannotPullContainerError”

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-batch

I have a cloud Formation template for a AWS Batch POC with 6 resources.

- 3 AWS::IAM::Role
- 1 AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment
- 1 AWS::Batch::JobQueue
- 1 AWS::Batch::JobDefinition

The AWS::IAM::Role have the policy "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess" (In order to avoid issues.)

The roles are used:

- 1 into the AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment
- 2 into the AWS::Batch::JobDefinition

But even with the policy "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess" I get "CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: Get https://********.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)" when I rin a job.

**Disclainer: All is FARGATE (Compute enviroment and Job), not EC2**

```yaml
        AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
        Description: Creates a POC AWS Batch environment.
        Parameters:
          Environment:
            Type: String
            Description: 'Environment Name'
            Default: TEST
          Subnets:
            Type: List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>
            Description: 'List of Subnets to boot into'
          ImageName:
            Type: String
            Description: 'Name and tag of Process Container Image'
            Default: 'upload:6.0.0'

        Resources:
          BatchServiceRole:
            Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
            Properties:
              RoleName: !Join ['', ['Demo', BatchServiceRole]]
              AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: 2012-10-17
                Statement:
                  - Effect: 'Allow'
                    Principal:
                      Service: 'batch.amazonaws.com'
                    Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
              ManagedPolicyArns:
                - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess'
          BatchContainerRole:
            Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
            Properties:
              RoleName: !Join ['', ['Demo', BatchContainerRole]]
              AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: 2012-10-17
                Statement:
                  - 
                    Effect: 'Allow'
                    Principal:
                      Service:
                        - 'ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com'
                    Action: 
                      - 'sts:AssumeRole'
              ManagedPolicyArns:
                - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess'
          BatchJobRole:
            Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
            Properties:
              RoleName: !Join ['', ['Demo', BatchJobRole]]
              AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
                Version: 2012-10-17
                Statement:
                  - Effect: 'Allow'
                    Principal:
                      Service: 'ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com'
                    Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
              ManagedPolicyArns:
                - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AdministratorAccess'
          BatchCompute:
            Type: "AWS::Batch::ComputeEnvironment"
            Properties:
              ComputeEnvironmentName: DemoContentInput
              ComputeResources: 
                MaxvCpus: 256 
                SecurityGroupIds:
                  - sg-0b33333333333333
                Subnets: !Ref Subnets
                Type: FARGATE
              ServiceRole: !Ref BatchServiceRole
              State: ENABLED
              Type: Managed
          Queue:
            Type: "AWS::Batch::JobQueue"
            DependsOn: BatchCompute
            Properties:
              ComputeEnvironmentOrder: 
                - ComputeEnvironment: DemoContentInput 
                  Order: 1
              Priority: 1
              State: "ENABLED"
              JobQueueName: DemoContentInput
          ContentInputJob:
            Type: "AWS::Batch::JobDefinition"
            Properties:
              Type: Container
              ContainerProperties: 
                Command: 
                  - -v
                  - process
                  - new-file
                  - -o
                  - s3://contents/{content_id}/{content_id}.mp4
                Environment:
                  - Name: SECRETS
                    Value: !Join [ ':', [ '{{resolve:secretsmanager:common.secrets:SecretString:aws_access_key_id}}', '{{resolve:secretsmanager:common.secrets:SecretString:aws_secret_access_key}}' ] ] 
                  - Name: APPLICATION 
                    Value: upload
                  - Name: API_KEY 
                    Value: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:common.secrets:SecretString:fluzo.api_key}}'
                  - Name: CLIENT
                    Value: upload-container
                  - Name: ENVIRONMENT
                    Value: !Ref Environment
                  - Name: SETTINGS
                    Value: !Join [ ':', [ '{{resolve:secretsmanager:common.secrets:SecretString:aws_access_key_id}}', '{{resolve:secretsmanager:common.secrets:SecretString:aws_secret_access_key}}', 'upload-container' ] ] 
                ExecutionRoleArn: 'arn:aws:iam::**********:role/DemoBatchJobRole'
                Image: !Join ['', [!Ref 'AWS::AccountId','.dkr.ecr.', !Ref 'AWS::Region', '.amazonaws.com/', !Ref ImageName ] ] 
                JobRoleArn: !Ref BatchContainerRole
                ResourceRequirements:
                  - Type: VCPU
                    Value: 1
                  - Type: MEMORY
                    Value: 2048
              JobDefinitionName: DemoContentInput
              PlatformCapabilities:
                - FARGATE
              RetryStrategy: 
                Attempts: 1
              Timeout: 
                AttemptDurationSeconds: 600
```

Into **AWS::Batch::JobQueue:ContainerProperties:ExecutionRoleArn** I harcoded the arn because if write **!Ref BatchJobRole** I get an error. But it's no my goal with this question.

The question is how to avoid "CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: Get https://********.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)" when I run a Job.

Comment: I think connection timeout related to network issues, how about checking the routing, NAT GW, security group?

Comment: Are you `!Ref Subnets` public subnets or private ones? How is your VPC configured?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you can't reach the internet from inside your subnet.

Make sure:

- There is an internet gateway device associated with your VPC (create one if there isn't -- even if you are just using nat-gateway for egress)
- The route table that is associated with your subnet has a default route (0.0.0./0) to an internet gateway or nat-gateway with an attached elastic-ip.
- An attached security group has rules allowing outbound internet traffic (0.0.0.0/0) for your ports and protocols. (e.g. 80/http, 443/https)
- The network access control list (network ACL) that is associated with the subnet has rules allowing both outbound and inbound traffic to the internet.

References:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-connect-internet-gateway/